# How to run multiple Angular Bootstrap versions at the same time without conflict?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have my site running with Angular Bootstrap v1.3.2 and everything works great. I am however being forced to add an in-house typeahead module which was built around Angular Bootstrap v0.13. I've tried running the module with the latest version of AB but it just doesn't function. It sadly doesn't throw any errors, which makes it hard to troubleshoot.

Reverting the whole site back to AB v0.13 results in multiple errors on my code.

I've seen that bower can host multiple package versions and tried running both the new and old together, but get modal provider errors. Is there a way to specify a specific AB version for a specific bit of code? Or at least allow the 2 versions to cooperate?

Comment: Hi @TheMean Won, did you get some work around this? I am in exact (but reverse) situation. My entire application is build around 0.11 and I am trying to use a module [angular-surveys](https://github.com/mwasiluk/angular-surveys), which is built on top of v1.3.

Comment: @RumitParakhiya - Sadly I was never able to get around this, so I drew a line in the sand and demanded all custom packages be at a certain version level before I'd even look at them. This has worked out well.